# jquery Modal and first tigger didnt working well

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have problem whit my modal and datepicker, i have table, with a link, where this link show up modal. this my code :

```
table.find('tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
            var code = $(this).find('a').text();
            var modal = $('.bs-modal-lg');
            var modalData = jQuery.parseJSON(ajaxPOST(code,'ajax/'+tblDetail,null,true));

            modal.find('.modal-title').html(modalData.title);
            modal.find('.modal-body').html(modalData.body);
            modal.find('.modal-footer').html(modalData.footer);

            modal.modal('show');
        });
```

and this my modal function :

```
$('.modal').on('click','button[data-dismiss=modal]',function(){
        $('.modal-title').html('');
        $('.modal-body').html('');
        $('.modal-footer').html('');
    })
```

Well is showing my modal, on inside my dialog i have table. Each table i have 3 input datepitcher, and in footer dialog i have 2 button colse and submit. And my problem is, my modal kinda little buggy. So if i click my button or input datepicker (same input) it didnt working at all, but when i click another input it will working until i close my dialog, but when i reopen again, is still same like first i open, i must click another input to make it working (except close button). Can anyone help me??

Edit this my modal

```
<?php

$json = array();

$info = $data["info"]->fetch_assoc();
$info_detail = $data['info_detail'];

//var_dump($info_attachment != '');

$json['title'] = 'Details Request Kontrabon';
$json['body'] = '<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">Request Number :</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 detail-no-req">'.$info['noreqvendor'].'</div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
$json['body'] .= '<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">Request Date :</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">'.$info['eordate'].'</div>
                    </div>
                </div>';



$json['body'] .= '<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                    <form>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" id="tbl_podet">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="10%">Item Description</th>
                                <th width="10%">Color</th>
                                <th width="10%">Size</th>
                                <th width="10%">PI Qty</th>
                                <th width="10%">PI Date</th>
                                <th width="10%">ETD</th>
                                <th width="10%">ETA</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>';


$iamount = 0;
$iQtyShip = 0;
$iCost = 0;
$iCosting = 0;
while($row = $info_detail->fetch_assoc()) {

    $json['body'] .= '<tr>';
    $json['body'] .= '<td>'.$row['itemdesc'].'</td>';
    $json['body'] .= '<td>'.$row['colorcode'].'</td>';
    $json['body'] .= '<td>'.$row['size'].'</td>';
    if($row['Qty']==0)
    {
        $disable = 'disabled';
    }
    else
    {
        $disable = '';
    }
    $json['body'] .= '<td class="text-right">
                           <input type="text" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" class="form-control input-lg" value="'.$row['Qty'].'" '.$disable.'>
                      </td>';
    $json['body'] .= '<td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control format-datepicker" id="pidate" style="z-index:99999;" type="text" value="'.$row['PIDate'].'">
                            </div>
                      </td>';
    $json['body'] .= '<td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control format-datepicker" id="ETD" style="z-index:99999;" type="text" value="'.$row['ETD'].'">
                            </div>
                      </td>';
    $json['body'] .= '<td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control format-datepicker" id="ETA" style="z-index:99999;" type="text" value="'.$row['ETA'].'">
                            </div>
                      </td>';
    $json['body'] .= '</tr>';

}
$json['body'] .= '</tbody></table></form></div></div>';

$json['footer'] .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-o modal-close pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
                        close
                    </button>';
    $json['footer'] .= '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-o modal-confirm" id="checkbtn" data-status="1">
                        Check
                    </button>';
// AND $info['PONo'] == ''

echo json_encode($json);
```

NOTE : I'm using ajax modal and framework laravel for this code

UPDATE : Closed i figured out, i must use `$(document).on('focus'` to get event.

Comment: would like to see you modal as well

Comment: @ScanQR ahh.. Yes,i'm sorry i will edit my question.

Comment: @ScanQR okay i update my question, i'm using json for modal and using framework laravel.